# How to use trigger tag values in webhook alert script in Zabbix?

Tags: zabbix

I would like to use trigger specific values in webhook alert script parameters in Zabbix (eg. wiki link, whether to send SMS).

When I use `{EVENT.TAGS}` macro, I get a comma separated list of event tags and their values: TAG1:TAG1value, TAG2:TAG2value, TAG3:TAG3value, ...

But when I try to get the value of a specific tag with `{EVENT.TAGS.<tag name>}` macro, for example with {EVENT.TAGS.ALERTWIKILINK}, the value does not get passed to webhook script. It gets passed as: {EVENT.TAGS.ALERTWIKILINK}.

I have been debugging with Zabbix webhook eventlog.

Zabbix version is 4.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with a few lines of javascript.

```js
var parameters = {};
var csv = 'TAG1:TAG1value, TAG2:TAG2value, TAG3:TAG3value';

if (csv) {
    var csvArray = csv.split(', ');
    console.log(csvArray)

    csvArray.forEach(function (item) {
        var itemArray = item.split(':');
        parameters[itemArray[0]] = itemArray[1];
    });

    console.log(parameters);
    console.log(parameters.TAG1);
}
```

With this code parameters variable gets populated with tag key/value pairs.

**EDIT**: This was fixed in a newer version.